# How to make this MySQL query work faster if I can not do indexing and partition?

Tags: mysql, zabbix

I am building web application around Zabbix MySQL (MariaDB) database.

I need to display table with all hostnames and list of current problems for the hosts, I do the following sql query (during one http GET request I do 7 such sql queries with different events.name values to check all possible problem)  to do so:

```
SELECT distinct(hosts.hostid), max(CONVERT(CONCAT(events.eventid, events.value, events.severity), UNSIGNED))
FROM hosts
INNER JOIN hosts_groups ON hosts.hostid = hosts_groups.hostid
INNER JOIN hstgrp ON hosts_groups.groupid = hstgrp.groupid

INNER JOIN items ON hosts.hostid = items.hostid
INNER JOIN functions ON items.itemid = functions.itemid
INNER JOIN events ON functions.triggerid = events.objectid
WHERE events.name = %s
AND hstgrp.groupid = %s
AND hosts.status != 3 # 3 - not templates
GROUP BY hosts.hostid;
```

The sum time of the sql queries can range from 20 seconds to 120 seconds, I suppose that the issue is related to the size of events table and the fact that new events are added to the table really fast.

The results of EXPLAIN command:
[image]

I suppose that I can try to do indexing of events.name column, but I am afraid that it can be negative factor for Zabbix application. Another option is partition but Zabbix have its' own partition howto plan, so I afraid to do it too.

What other options do I have to make the query work faster and what can be the reason of such a great difference in the query time (up to 6-7 times)?

**EDIT:**

If I restrict time of events e.g. up to 10 last days, the queries work faster, but I loose some of events, since error event could take place 1 month ago and never was not solved then.

```
SELECT hosts.hostid, max(CONVERT(CONCAT(events.eventid, events.value, events.severity), UNSIGNED))
FROM hosts
INNER JOIN hosts_groups ON hosts.hostid = hosts_groups.hostid
INNER JOIN hstgrp ON hosts_groups.groupid = hstgrp.groupid

INNER JOIN items ON hosts.hostid = items.hostid
INNER JOIN functions ON items.itemid = functions.itemid
INNER JOIN events ON functions.triggerid = events.objectid
WHERE events.eventid >= (select eventid from events  where events.clock >= 1602773508 limit 1) AND events.name = "Устройство недоступно"
AND hstgrp.groupid = 15
AND hosts.status != 3 # 3 - not templates
GROUP BY hosts.hostid;
```

**EDIT**

The results from problem table contradict to results from events table, hosts which are called not reachable table are available by ping and not marked as not reachable in zabbix intereface, query:

```
SELECT distinct(hosts.hostid) FROM hosts
INNER JOIN hosts_groups ON hosts.hostid = hosts_groups.hostid
INNER JOIN hstgrp ON hosts_groups.groupid = hstgrp.groupid

INNER JOIN items ON hosts.hostid = items.hostid
INNER JOIN functions ON items.itemid = functions.itemid
INNER JOIN problem ON functions.triggerid = problem.objectid
WHERE problem.name = "Device is unreachable"
AND hstgrp.groupid = 15
AND hosts.status != 3 ;
```

In addition I found that for one host there are several problems with the same name but different time (clock), though I expected maximum one problem with the specified name for the concrete host:

```
SELECT hosts.hostid, problem.name, problem.clock FROM hosts
INNER JOIN hosts_groups ON hosts.hostid = hosts_groups.hostid
INNER JOIN hstgrp ON hosts_groups.groupid = hstgrp.groupid

INNER JOIN items ON hosts.hostid = items.hostid
INNER JOIN functions ON items.itemid = functions.itemid
INNER JOIN problem ON functions.triggerid = problem.objectid
WHERE problem.name = "Device is unreachable"
AND hstgrp.groupid = 15
AND hosts.status != 3 ;
```

Results for one host from problems table:

10398  Device is unreachable  1603625463
10398  Device is unreachable  1603630863
10398  Device is unreachable  1603661463
10398  Device is unreachable  1603679463
10398  Device is unreachable  1603697463

Comment: for Optimization questions you need to provide more information , all indexes you have, further an EXPLAIN of your query

Comment: @nbk sorry my mistake I wrote incorrect name describe instead of EXPLAIN

Comment: your viggest set is events nwith almost a million entries, have you tried to miminize that amunt

Comment: Did you try with APIs instead of accessing the DB directly?

Comment: @nbk I tried to make restrictions based on events.clock (though it could be incorrect since last error could happen 2 month ago and still be active), but is didn't make the query any faster.

Comment: @SimoneZabberoni yes I have checked what Zabbix APU can offer in the situation but since I need to make some kind of report about all current problems of a certain hosts group (the largest one is 2768 hosts) I decided to go with database directly.

Comment: I think that you are asking too much to the database with this 5 joins query. 
I've done reports on similar scale setup with a few api call (host.get plus probem.get) and by "doing the math" at script level, usually run from a different machine.

Comment: @SimoneZabberoni Thanks, I was suggested in another forum to create another table, which will be much smaller subset of  events table and update it with some script with new events every 5-7 minutes (which is fine for the app since it is some kind of report, but close enough to current hosts status). Then do JOIN with the new smaller table instead of events table. Can it improve situation from your opinion?

Comment: That's actually worse. Everything you need is already available, there's no need for new tables and some tool to keep it synched. You need a report on current problems on the hosts of an host group: that's a single API call, problem.get with a groupids filter and maybe an extended output, then work on the results.

Comment: Because the API call does not make a 5 join query, with max/convert/concat (otherwise the Zabbix Dashboard on his server wouldn't load). The best course of action, advised by Zabbix as well, is to use API to query the data and not to query the db directly, then work on the results. Of course, the OP can use a simplified query, but why use it when you already have the tools?

Comment: @SimoneZabberoni well according to our Zabbix administrator, Zabbix do not offer the kind of report out of box, so probably the kind of query is slow by default, what I can not understand at all why the same query time can be from 1 to 20 seconds.

Comment: Btw, the `distinct(hosts.hostid)` is incorrect use of `distinct`. `distinct` is not an aggregate function, but row-level clause which removes duplicates from the result set. As you already have the `GROUP BY hosts.hostid` in your query, the result set will already have just one row per hostid. No need to use the `distinct` at all.

Comment: @slaakso thanks a lot, it did not know it !

Comment: Another important thing, I have to ask again: are you looking for *current* problems (on a host or group) or for *all* problems?

Comment: @SimoneZabberoni I am looking for all active problems (list of 7 event names now) for all hosts in the chosen group/groups

Comment: Then I think that you are joining the wrong table: `events` contains everything that ever happened (so it's huge), while the `problem` table contains only the active issues

Comment: @SimoneZabberoni thanks I'll check that one

Comment: @SimoneZabberoni I've checked problem table and got some unexpected results, described them in edit of the question. Could you check please?

Comment: @SimoneZabberoni e.g. I found in the problem table a problem for one host, so I expected that it is active problem, but actully it was solved one hour ago: Start 26-10-2020 11:07:42 End 26-10-2020 11:37:42 UTC+3 And device is really reachable now.

Comment: Yes, that's how problem works. From https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/current/manual/api/reference/problem/get : "This method is for retrieving unresolved problems. It is also possible, if specified, to additionally retrieve recently resolved problems"

Comment: Addition: "Problems that were resolved prior to that period are not kept in the problem table."

Comment: @SimoneZabberoni yes I found that r_clock if != 0 is the correct time of problem resolution. Many thanks to you! Please make your last message as an asnwe and I'll mark it as solution for the question. Thank you very much indeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer "built" from the comments.

While the best course of action is to use the `problem.get` API, from the [documentation](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/current/manual/api/reference/problem/get) you can infer how the `problem` table works and use it for a SQL query:

> This method is for retrieving unresolved problems. It is also
> possible, if specified, to additionally retrieve recently resolved
> problems. The period that determines how old is “recently” is defined
> in Administration → General.
>
> Problems that were resolved prior to that
> period are not kept in the problem table. To retrieve problems that
> were resolved further back in the past, use the event.get method.

You should join that table and not the `events` table, which contains every event that happened in the past.

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot create an index on events.name or hstgrp.groupid you are out of luck. If you already have an index on events.name, try forcing the use of that index using an index hint, e.g. `JOIN events FORCE INDEX (index_name)`. You may also have to re-arrange the JOIN order to put the events table at the front and use a STRAIGHT_JOIN to prevent the optimized from reordering the join. If it doesn't help (or it makes things worse), there is not much else that can be done.

Edit:
Try this:

Extend the index on events(objectid) to events(objectid, name) and change the query to:

```
SELECT distinct(hosts.hostid), 
max(CONVERT(CONCAT(events.eventid, events.value, 
events.severity), UNSIGNED))
FROM hosts
INNER JOIN hosts_groups ON hosts.hostid = hosts_groups.hostid
INNER JOIN hstgrp ON hosts_groups.groupid = hstgrp.groupid 
INNER JOIN items ON hosts.hostid = items.hostid
INNER JOIN functions ON items.itemid = functions.itemid
INNER JOIN events ON functions.triggerid = events.objectid AND events.name = %s
WHERE hstgrp.groupid = %s
AND hosts.status != 3 # 3 - not templates
GROUP BY hosts.hostid;
```

Comment: Thanks, I was suggested in another forum to create another table, which will be much smaller subset of  events table and update it with some script with new events every 5-7 minutes (which is fine for the app since it is some kind of report, but close enough to current hosts status). Then do JOIN with the new smaller table instead of events table. Can it improve situation from your opinion?

Comment: please see my comment on the original answer

Comment: If that table is massively smaller, yes. But if that is the case you can gain a similar advantage by forcing an index as I described.

Comment: @GordanBobic actually STRAIGHT_JOIN make the query about two times slower, what I can not understand at all why the same query time can be from 1 to 20 seconds. I paid attention that Zabbix often took all available connections to database (200 connections limit for the db now), can it be related to high query intensity?

Comment: My first guess would be the query cache. Do all runs take 20s with `query_cache_type=0`?

Comment: @ArtiomKozyrev I just update the answer with another thing to try.

Comment: @GordanBobic for cache purpose I am going to add Redis to the project, since I have quite limited access to this database (e.g. can not change indexing and use temp tables), I guess that eventually I'll have to limit time of events to some range e.g. 10 days. For good (not when db is busy with smth) it is 8 sec (10 days limit) against 23 sec (about 40 days, db was created about 40 days ago).

Comment: To emulate `query_cache_type=0`, you can `SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE ...` in your query to see if that completely disappears the runs that are faster than 20 seconds.

Comment: @GordanBobic yes sometimes it is faster to add another piece of software (Redis in the case) then to persuade another person to make changes to db like use of cache.

Comment: @GordanBobic tried ```SQL_NO_CACHE``` the speed of queries is the same (good case) now.

Comment: Great, so you must have been running into the query cache issues. It is why that feature was removed in MySQL 8.x